# A regex to match anything 2 digits and above

Tags: javascript, regex, match

The title is self explanatory. I need help with getting a regex that will match anything 2 digits and above thanks

Comment: Something like this: `.*\d.*\d.*` ?

Answer (score 1):

If your string is just digits, and you want to make sure there are at least 2 or more, then this:

```js
var str = '12';
if (str.match(/\d{2,}/)) {
  console.log('match');
}
```

If your string can be anything, but you want to make sure there are at least two digits in it, consecutive or not, then the suggestion in the comments will work.